# How can I create an e-mail field on a Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

When making a Google Form, how can I mark the field as "e-mail" so that it is validated as an e-mail before the user can submit the form?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- Choose the question type as Text
- Click on Advanced settings
- Check Data Validation
- Choose Text
- Choose Email Address
- (optional) Type in a custom error message

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a solution to this problem; however, you must disconnect the form from being hosted on Google's servers in order to accomplish this.

The idea is that you copy the form HTML to your server.  The form itself **will continue to submit data to Google Spreadsheets**, but you will have full control over the look and feel of the form.

Be forewarned!  Since it's disconnected from Google's Servers, any updates to Google Forms or Spreadsheets could necessitate the need to copy the new HTML or JavaScript code to your Web server.

My suggestion is to **post the form data to Google as well as another location** to prevent data loss when non-backwards compatible updates are made.

You can find more information on [Morning Copy - Google Forms and JQuery Validation](http://morning.am/tutorials/google-forms-and-jquery-validation/) and [Morning Copy - How to Style Google Forms](http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/).

Read the styling guide first, as this includes instructions on how to extract the HTML.  Afterwards, read the Validation guide, which specifically addresses the steps required to solve your validation problem.

Comment: I fixed the broken links. As an aside, next time just say something and I'll fix them. :)  Hope this helps.